# How To Set character_limiter() in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, character

I'm new to Codeigniter. Now I want to set the character limit in the view. First, get the data from the database with $query_result->result(), and then show it in the view using foreach().

Here is my Controller, Model and View:

```
public function index() {
$data = array();
$data['category'] = $this->product_model->selectAllcategory();
$data['randProduct'] = $this->product_model->selectRandomProduct();
$data['products'] = $this->product_model->selectAllProduct();
$data['maincontent'] = $this->load->view('home', $data, true);
$data['title'] = 'Welcome Russel Store';
$this->load->view('index', $data);
}
```

And my Model:

```
public function selectAllProduct() {
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('product');
$this->db->where('status', 1);
$this->db->order_by('product_id', 'desc');
$query_result = $this->db->get();
$result = $query_result->result();
return $result;
}
```

And I want to set the character limit in the View:

```
http://russelstore.mastersite.info

echo character_limiter($result->product_title, 25);
```

Comment: character_limiter() should do that just fine. I'm confused as to what your question is.

Comment: @Ebrahim, when formatting your code for StackOverflow, you don't need <pre> tags or backticks. Just indent all the lines with four spaces. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/text_helper.html

You should import **Text Helper**

in your controller, it is a good practice to load helper, models and libraries in **a constructor**

```
function __construct()
{
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->helper('text');
  $this->load->model('products_model'); //name of your model class

}

function index()
{
  $data['products']=$this->products_model->selectAllProduct();
  $this->load->view('index',$data);
}
```

at your view index.php

```
//This is an example from CI's home page        
//$string = "Here is a nice text string consisting of eleven words.";            
//$string = word_limiter($string, 4);

    foreach($products as $p)
    {
        $limited_word = word_limiter($p[product_title],25);
        echo $limited_word;
    }
```

Comment: please kindly mark as answer if that solved your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use my code there

```
<?php $artikel=$a->isi;$artikel=character_limiter($artikel,200); ?>
            <p><?php echo $artikel ?></p>
            <a href="<?php echo base_url()."index_cont/list_artikel_kat/".$a->id_artikel; ?>" target="_blank">Selanjutnya</a>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First Load the helper class in either `autoload.php` or in the `controller` class.

For Global use , write in **`Autoload.php`**:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('text');
```

OR If you want to use only in one **`controller.php`** class then:

```
function __construct()
{
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->helper('text');
}
```

Then in your **`view.php`**:

```
<?php 
  if(!empty($ques)) {
    foreach($ques as $list) { 
      $title = character_limiter($list->Title, 80); // Here we are setting the title character limit to 80
      <?php echo $title;?>
    }
  }
?>
```