# Word_limiter function in foreach via codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<div id="one">

<?php foreach($m_post as $row){ ?>
   <!-- medium -->
   <div id="profile-page-wall-post" class="col s4 card">
        <div class="card-profile-title">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s10">
                    <span class="grey-text text-darken-1 ultra-small">Shared publicly  on <?php echo  $row->date_added; ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="card-image profile-medium"> 

    <?php foreach(unserialize($m_post[0]->post_image) as $a){ ?>              
        <img src="<?php echo base_url()."assets/".$a?>" alt="sample" class="responsive-img profile-post-image profile-medium">                        
    <?php } ?> 
    
    <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
    </div>

    <div class="card-content">
        <p><?php echo word_limiter($row->post,15); ?></p>
    </div>
    <center> 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color:#00BCD4">Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color:#00BCD4">Delete</button><br><br>
    </center>
</div>
<!-- medium video -->
<br><br>
```

Here I have to limit the words which comes from database upto 15 only in codeigniter. But it shows this error:

#### Error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function word_limiter() in
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/ci/post/application/views/my_admin/profile1.php on
> line 172

Comment: are you sure that you've [loaded the helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/text_helper.html#loading-this-helper)?

Comment: you can load helper file first. **$this->load->helper('text');** [link](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/text_helper.html)

Comment: Refer this    StackOverflow solution , it might helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16175851/how-to-set-character-limiter-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function word_limiter()

Your Error Clearly Shows that You Need to load the helper first. Here is the Code.

```
function __construct()
{
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->helper('text');
}
```